# Writing a program without using .activate/.select. VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have read online in many different places that I should not use `.activate` or commands like it. problem is my program HEAVILY relies on them.

Let me give some background first. I am writing a program to automate a part of my job. I have already written this particular portion of code months ago, and it worked perfectly well. However now that I am trying to update the code things that use to work are causing errors. namely the instances of `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial`. I read that it is the `.activate` that is causing the problem. Why is this only causing a problem now?

As for the main question I need my code to do 4 things

1. get a account number from a specific cell.
2. activate "sheet2" paste text date copied from a outside Program to "A1" and collect text data from different cells on "sheet2" based on the pasted data.
3. activate "sheet1" paste data collected and receive the next account number.
4. Switch between Excel and another program that only accepts keyboard entry. 
   While this step is annoying it is not the step I need help on.

Here is the code I have so far. I know how to do most of the steps I am just lost when trying to get it done without `.activate`.

```
   Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
        'find missing emails
Dim e As Range, Rang As Range
Set Rang = Range("A2:A100")

AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
Worksheets("Email_List").Activate
Range("A1").Activate

For Each e In Rang
    If Not IsEmpty(e.Value) = True Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Sleep 700
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Activate
        Sleep 700
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Activate
            Sleep 700
            ActiveCell.Copy
            Sleep 700
            AppActivate "Other Program"
            Sleep 500
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "1", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "2", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "1", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "~", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "c ", True
            Sleep 700
            SendKeys "^v", True
            Sleep 7001
            SendKeys "^x", True
            Sleep 7000
            SendKeys "^a", True
            Sleep 7000
            SendKeys "^c", True
            Sleep 7000
            AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
            Sleep 500
            Worksheets("Data").Activate
            Cells.Activate
            Cells.Delete
            Range("A1").Activate
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
            Sleep 500
                If Range("A24").Value = "CONF# NOT FOUND, PRESS <ENTER>" Then
                    Sleep 700
                    AppActivate "Other Program"
                    Sleep 500
                    SendKeys "~", True
                    Sleep 700
                    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
                    Sleep 500
                    Worksheets("Email_List").Activate
                ElseIf Range("A24").Value = "ENTER RESERVATION NUMBER:" Then
                    Range("D24").Activate
                    ActiveCell.Value = "=LEFT(A6,6)"
                    ActiveCell.Copy
                    AppActivate "Other Program"
                    Sleep 500
                    SendKeys "^v", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "30", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "~", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "^x", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "^a", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "^c", True
                    Sleep 700
                    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
                    Sleep 500
                    Worksheets("Data").Activate
                    Cells.Activate
                    Cells.Delete
                    Range("A1").Activate
                    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
                    Sleep 500
                        If Range("A8").Value = "3. E-FOLIO" Then
                            Sleep 700
                            AppActivate "Other Program"
                            Sleep 500
                            SendKeys ("3")
                            Sleep 700
                            SendKeys ("~")
                            Sleep 700
                            SendKeys "^x", True
                            Sleep 700
                            SendKeys "^a", True
                            Sleep 700
                            SendKeys "^c", True
                            Sleep 700
                            AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
                            Sleep 500
                            Worksheets("Data").Activate
                            Cells.Activate
                            Cells.Delete
                            Range("A1").Activate
                            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
                            Sleep 700
                            Range("A21").Copy
                            Worksheets("Email_List").Activate
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Activate
                            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Activate
                        End If
                ElseIf Range("A2").Value = "===============================================================================" Then
                    AppActivate "Other Program"
                    Sleep 500
                    SendKeys "30", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "~", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "^x", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "^a", True
                    Sleep 700
                    SendKeys "^c", True
                    Sleep 700
                    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
                    Sleep 500
                    Worksheets("Data").Activate
                    Cells.Activate
                    Cells.Delete
                    Range("A1").Activate
                    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
                    Sleep 500
                        If Range("A8").Value = "3. E-FOLIO" Then
                            Sleep 700
                            AppActivate "Other Program"
                            Sleep 500
                            SendKeys ("3")
                            Sleep 700
                            SendKeys ("~")
                            Sleep 700
                            SendKeys "^x", True
                            Sleep 700
                            SendKeys "^a", True
                            Sleep 700
                            SendKeys "^c", True
                            Sleep 700
                            AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
                            Sleep 500
                            Worksheets("Data").Activate
                            Cells.Activate
                            Cells.Delete
                            Range("A1").Activate
                            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
                            Sleep 500
                            Range("A21").Copy
                            Worksheets("Email_List").Activate
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Activate
                            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Activate
                        End If
                End If
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Activate
        End If
    End If

Next e
End Sub
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I will re-post this question there then. Thank you for directing me to the right place.

Comment: Can't wait to review it on CR - see you on the other side! :-)

Comment: Good cause I have a lot to learn about VBA, and coding in general.

Comment: Argh, I misread the question - you need to first get the code to work as intended, *then* it can be peer reviewed on CR. I suggest you [edit] this post to ask *specifically* about the error you're getting, and only include the code that's needed to reproduce the problem - see [mcve].

Comment: Exactly what is the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

Start here:

> ```
> Worksheets("Email_List").Activate
> Range("A1").Activate
> ```

You have a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` that's *labelled* "Email_List". Its actual `(Name)` property might be `Sheet12`; hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the *Project Explorer*, then select the "Email_List" sheet under the "Microsoft Excel Objects" folder, and hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the *Properties* toolwindow. Locate the `(Name)` property (should be the very first on top) and change `Sheet12` (or whatever) to `EmailListSheet`.

Now back to your code, you no longer need to *find* the worksheet - you *have* a reference to it already.

```
EmailListSheet.Range("A1").Activate
```

Will do exactly the same thing as this:

> ```
> Worksheets("Email_List").Activate
> Range("A1").Activate
> ```

But you don't want to `.Activate` the range. Rather, you want to keep a reference to it. Declare a `Range` variable:

```
Dim workingRange As Range
Set workingRange = EmailListSheet.Range("A1")
```

Now instead of this:

> ```
>     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
>     Sleep 700
>     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Activate
>     Sleep 700
> ```

You can do that:

```
Set workingRange = workingRange.Offset(1, 3)
```

(no need to sleep here)

Next you want to see if that cell is empty:

> ```
> If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
> ```

So you'll just do this:

```
If IsEmpty(workingRange.Value) Then
```

Then you're copying another cell like this:

> ```
> ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Activate
> Sleep 700
> ActiveCell.Copy
> ```

Not sure what's up with all that sleeping, but anyway you'll be doing this instead:

```
workingRange.Offset(0, -3).Copy
```

Cue `SendKeys`, paste into the other application, and copy *from* that other application, and we get to the part that blows up:

> ```
> Worksheets("Data").Activate
> Cells.Activate
> Cells.Delete
> Range("A1").Activate
> ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
> ```

Same deal: name that worksheet `DataSheet` and work off a reference to that object.

```
DataSheet.UsedRange.Clear
DataSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

The rest is just more of the same.

Key points:

- Name your worksheets and use the global reference you get for free, instead of fetching all sheets from the `Worksheets` collection every time you need it.
- Avoid calling `Range` and `Cells` without qualifying them with a `Worksheet` object, e.g. `DataSheet.Range`. When they're not qualified, these members implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet`, which is what you want to avoid here.
- Once you get your code to work as intended, edit the revised code into [your Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146031/23788) to  get that post reopened and your new working code peer reviewed and further improved.